# PHP SOAP call parameters for GUID

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, soap

I'm implementing a web service for one of my clients and the method requires 3 parameters (username, password) and an empty GUID which should be passed in as a reference. I've tried multiple options but cannot figure out what the issue is. Any ideas?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <LogonAndRequestToken xmlns="">
       <username>string</username>
       <password>string</password>
       <guid>guid</guid>
     </LogonAndRequestToken>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

I am using the following code at the moment:

```
       //$guid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
       if($this->utilities->ping()->PingResult->ErrorCode == 0) {
           pr($this->utilities->LogonAndRequestToken(array("username" => "username", "password" => "pass", "guid" => 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)));
       }
       exit;
```

pr() is a shorthand function for print_r() and I have tried the GUID as is now and also the commented out version. With the version now I get an exception thrown that the GUID is not the correct format and the commented out one gives a response from the server but indicates that there is a 10001 error (technical error and that I should contact support). 
As I am convinced the username and password is correct I am sure I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Here is some more info:

From the service description:

```
 <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
           <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="username" type="s:string"/>
           <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
           <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="guid" type="s1:guid"/>
      </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
```

I also tried the following option:
     array(...,"guid" => &$guid)

Comment: The GUID isn't valid. You need to specify the version and variant of the used guid algorithm. There is no "default", empty guid you could pass. Either it's a guid or not. Have you tried to pass an empty string?

Comment: I have tried an empty string and reference to an empty variable: There is an error in XML document (2, 242). ---> System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format. at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure

Comment: Have you tried to generate a guid? like this: http://php.net/manual/de/function.uniqid.php#107512 ?

Comment: can you paste your wsdl part, where this guid element is defined? you are sending string while your webservice is expecting object of type s1:guid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by implimenting the PHP COM plugin and using the com_create_guid function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a guid by php like this:

```
public static function GenerateGuid()
{
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version"
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,
        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low"
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        // 48 bits for "node"
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959